# How can I export test step description as plain text?

Tags: quality-center, excel, export

I'm using an Excel report from Analysis view to export the design steps to Excel:

```
SELECT DESSTEPS.DS_DESCRIPTION
FROM DESSTEPS
```

However, DESSTEPS.DS_DESCRIPTION field looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div align="left"><font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:8pt">Call transaction </span></font><font 
face="Arial" size="3"><span style="font-size:10pt">SU01</span></font></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in Excel the corresponding cell looks like this:

```
<empty line>
<empty line>
<empty line>
<empty line>
Call transaction SU01
<empty line>
<empty line>
<empty line>
<empty line>
```

Is there a way to convert the HTML content to plain text (in the SQL query or in post-processing) in order to avoid blank lines in Excel?

Environment:

- ALM 11
- Oracle 10

Comment: I'm here again and I continue with this problem, I get 4 lines blank with html fields using Excel report, do you find the answer to fix it?...

Comment: Hi Tania! Could you move your comment from answer to comment under the question?

Comment: Converted Tania's answer to a comment - thanks for the heads up @dzieciou

Answer (score 2):

What operating system are you using?  If it is *nix, you could use html2text.

Comment: Sadly, Windows only environment :(

Comment: If you download cygwin, then you could download and build html2text on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to export in Excel the description of test step, the best way is to use, in the module dashboard, the "Excel Report".
With this tool, you can create an Excel file with :

- for each request SQL an Excel sheet with the result of your request
- you can create VB code who is execute in post processing (to add graph, specific instruction, ...)

In the database, QC save all htlm tag for description. With "Excel Report", the result is only the text without html tag.

Comment: It is an Excel report, the problem is that in a cell the text has 4 blank lines before and after it.

Comment: Normally you may not see html tag with an Excel report. You can add a Post processing to suppress this kind of information. You must verify version and patch because if I remimber there is a patch for this. If you give me you version and patch I can check for you

Comment: ALM11 SP2 x64 (the latest, AFAIK)